# Visual Studio 2015 CSC errors

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I've been coding away without any issues and I found I needed to update some nuget packages and during the process my C: ran out of space.  Now that I've cleared up I'm just getting two bizarre errors, not with my code though:

```
The "Csc" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.          

The "ChecksumAlgorithm" parameter is not supported by the "Csc" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.
```

I've tried restarting VS and I'm running update 3
Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: MSBuild is broken.  Hard to imagine it has anything to do with out-of-space or cleanup.  More likely are the Nuget packages added stuff to your project file.  Remove them again to see if that clears up the error, have a look at the project file if necessary.  The ChecksumAlgorithm parameter was a [very recent addition](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10451)

Comment: Yeah it's all a little coincidental I think. I ended up recreatiung the project and carefully adding all the Owin and WebApi packages to have a clean app.  Seems to work but the offending "compilers" package is listed as available for updating in NuGet Package Manager.  I daren't upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I was helped by updating of libraries Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Microsoft.Net.Compilers with packages.config to later versions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.3" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net451" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>
```